# How to solve Bernoulli type equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking for hints on how to solve this equation :

$$xy^2y'=x^2+y^3$$

I know it's a  Bernoulli type differential equation, but I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: This is not a Bernouilli equation.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima depends on the definition but $y'=py^{-2}+Ry$ is a Bernouilli equation for $n<0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used variation of parameter to solve it

$$xy^2y'=x^2+y^3$$
$$\frac x3(y^3)'=x^2+y^3$$
$$\frac x3(y^3)'-y^3=x^2$$
Solving the homogeneous equation
$$\frac x3(y^3)'=y^3$$
$$\int \frac {d(y^3)}{y^3}=\int \frac {3dx}x=3\ln |x|+K$$
$$\ln|y^3|=3\ln |x|+K$$
$$y^3=Kx^3$$
$$y^3=K(x)x^3 \implies \frac x3(K(x)x^3)'-K(x)x^3=x^2$$
$$\frac 13K'x^4=x^2$$
$$K'=\frac 3 {x^2} \implies K= -\frac 3x+C$$
$$\boxed{y^3=(Cx-3)x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Try to substitute $u=y^3$, then $u'=3y^2y'$.

Or you can also try to do the $y=ux$ substitution.